i am facing an error while uploading images to cloud, error: "Must supply api_key"
i am using cloudinary for storing images with nodeJs environment, but facing this error Must supply api_key
this is cloud config file
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const { CloudinaryStorage} = require('multer-storage-cloudinary')

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUD_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_API_SECRET,
    secure: true
});

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    params:{
        folder: 'Civil_2_DEV',
        allowedFormats: ['png', 'jpeg', 'jpg']
    }
});

module.exports = {cloudinary, storage};

this is router file
const {storage, cloudinary} = require('../config/cloudConfig')
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({storage});

router.post('/test/create', 
    isLoggedIn, 
    upload.single('image'),
    validateTest, 
    createNewTest)

this is how i configured .env file
if(process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production'){
    require('dotenv').config({path: './config/config.env'})
}

i already checked the secrets with console log these are accessible in console, but still i am facing this error

The error "Must supply api_key" means Cloudinary isn't receiving your API key. Ensure your .env file has the correct values (CLOUD_NAME, CLOUD_API_KEY, CLOUD_API_SECRET), and they're loaded properly using dotenv.
